# How to install SILK workbench?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, linked-data

I want to install Silk - The Linked Data Integration Framework. I have downloaded latest version (2.6.1) of SILK WorkBench (https://github.com/silk-framework/silk/releases).  I want to install it in both Mac and Windows Machine. Project README file is saying that "The bin-folder contains scripts for running the Silk Workbench on Windows, Linux and iOS."  I have tried to run silk-workbench.bat file. However it is giving me following errors.

### Mac:

```
./silk-workbench.bat: line 1: @REM: command not found: command not foundt: line 2: @REM
./silk-workbench.bat: line 3: @REM: command not found
./silk-workbench.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./silk-workbench.bat: line 4: `@REM JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir (opti'nal if java on path)
```

### Windows:

The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Please let me know how to install SILK workbench.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! The problem is coming from the path of batch file as it is mentioned in the error that "The input line is too long".
Be sure that when you are exporting the files form .tgz or .tar format, don't create very nested path for batch file.
At first, my batch file was in this address:

```
F:/silk-workbench-2.7.1/silk-workbench-2.7.1/bin/
```

And I was facing the same problem. By moving the bin file to this path, I solve the problem:

```
 C:/silk-workbench-2.7.1/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

The sbt.bat tool is for windows. On other platforms -- including macs -- use sbt instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how on Mac

1) Download Silk from  https://github.com/silk-framework/silk/release and download the silk-workbench-2.6.1 ( you've probably already done this )

2) extract the tarball ( tar -xvf silk-workbench-2.6.1.tgz  )

3) move into the extracted directory , go into the bin folder and run the silk-workbench executable

( cd /silk-workbench-2.6.1/bin ;
 ./silkworkbench
)

It should be up and running on http://localhost:9000 on any browser

Comment: I do the same but when I am running the script I get the error of  "The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect." What should I do?