# Installing Silk Workbench on windows 10?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, data-integration, linked-data

I am using java 8 on Windows 10 and I have to use Silk linked data integration tool. 
I downloaded the latest version of Silk workbench from [github](https://github.com/silk-framework/silk/releases/tag/release-2.7.1). I actually do not know what should I do with it. It is mentioned in the readme that the bin folder contains the script for running the silk; however, my first question is that how can I run it from those two files (type: File and Window Batch File)?

The second question is which silk I should use? (Single Machine or Workbench)

The third question is whether Silk has any jar file that I can use it withing my java project or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions and ran this:

```
~/Downloads/silk-workbench-2.7.1 ᐅ sh bin/silk-workbench
Play server process ID is 19752
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

I was able to open this:

[image]

I would suspect you can execute

```
.\bin\silk-workbench.bat
```

And it should either complain about Java or work as on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I followed exactly the same approach but by executing the .bat file in bin folder I get this error:
`The input line is too long.` 
 `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
I don't know where the problem is exactly from, people mentioned to install sbt on my computer but I am not sure if the source of the problem is that.  do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You need to make sure that silk-workbench-2.7.1 is extracted to a folder without any spaces in the path and it's close to root (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065993/has-windows-7-fixed-the-255-character-file-path-limit for details). E.g. `C:\apps\silk-workbench-2.7.1`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the problem fixed! Problem was because of the path that contains the batch file. In fact, the path was too long (violate the path 260 character limitation). I change it and I got it fixed!

I provided more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413337/4262053